# Visual Studio Output Terminal

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

[vs2017screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzKpY.png)

The output terminal is not opening at all, not even popping out for a second as I saw in different compilers. How can I see the output "HI" please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)` to the `SubSystem` property. Right click on the project in Solution Explorer then `Properties->Linker->System`:
[image]